# Java 8 Spring Data JPA Parameter binding

Tags: jpa, java-8, jpql, spring-data-jpa

In my @Repository interface I created custom find method with JPQL @Query that contains parameter (addressType).

`from Address a where a.addressType = :addressType`

In the method I did not specify @Param("addressType") on the parameter. So I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.

Okay, this is pretty much clear, but I am using Java 8. So what is special about Java 8 here?

Comment: Oh dear, you have omitted "SELECT a" from your JPQL query, so it is now illegal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use reflection to access names of parameters of methods. This makes the `@Param` annotation unnecessary, since Spring can deduce the name of the JPQL parameter from the name of the method parameter.

But you need to use the `-parameters` flag with the compiler to have that information available.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm using Java8 and SpringData still asks me for the @Param annotation.

Comment: Have you compiled your classes with the -parameters option, as explained in the page I linked to?

Comment: No I did not try that, I decided just to stick with @Param annotation since code will not work without special compilation configuration. But this your comment explains what you meant in your main answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

The answer given by @JB Nizet is correct, but I just wanted to point out the way to add the `-parameters` flag for the Java 8 compiler when using Eclipse. This is in Window -> Preferences:

[image: Preferences setting]

Maven also allows adding the flags in the pom itself:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To add parameters flag for Java 8 compiler when using IDEA IntelliJ

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler

[image: Java Compiler setting]

Comment: Is this dependency or downlaod any jar files?

Comment: It's a maven plugin @Deva

Comment: So, this will increase my project size when I create war file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from JB Nizet and Xtreme Biker are both corrects. I just want to add that if you use Spring Boot the `-parameters` compiler flag is already added for you by [`spring-boot-starter-parent`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/build.gradle) (Gradle or Maven) :

```
plugin {
    delegate.groupId('org.apache.maven.plugins')
    delegate.artifactId('maven-compiler-plugin')
    configuration {
        delegate.parameters('true')
    }
}
```